# HP MSL2024 not auto changing tapes using Ultrabac 9.2.2

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage, hp, tape, tapedrive

I am using Ultrabac 9.2.2 to run backup sets to a one drive HP MSL2024 tape library. It's currently connected via SAS 3Gbs to a HP Proliant DL380G6 running Server 2008 R2. I have the drivers from HP installed, I just verified. However, in Device Manager is shows just a tape drive, and not library. Don't know if that has to do with the issue.

When running a backup set in Ultrabac after the tape fills up I am prompted to insert the next tape. I need this to cycle the full magazine. I have 40TB do backup and there is no way I can change the tape each time.

I have looked through all of the settings in Ultrabac, the MSL2024 web UI, and Windows. I cannot figure this out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: I have looked further into it, I have the library under Medium Changer Devices in Device Manager, I overlooked this earlier. I also performed a move test from HP Library Tape Tools and the device is functional mechanically.